# HTML code greyed out when inspecting mobile version of website

Tags: html, mobile, inspect, responsive

We have a responsive website which has a search field element showing at the very top centered horizontally. When you reduce the screen resolution to that of a tablet or mobile phone, the search field element disappears completely although if you inspect the code, the code is still there but the code is slightly greyed out and i guess this means it is disabled and therefore not shown.

How do i get this code to show in the tablet and mobile phone resolutions. How do i have this code not greyed out?

[image]

Comment: Is this a public site? Can you show us the CSS files you have?

Comment: your code inspector should have an option to view the "computed styles" of a given element. use that to determine why it's not showing (if it's responsive it's probably being hidden in a media query somewhere). the style viewer should tell you which file the styles came from as well. use that to determine which styles need to be changed. we can

Comment: 't help you without seeing the css, though you could try adding an inline style to the element directly `#searchwhateveritscalled{ display:block; }`

Answer (score 2):

Viewing your CSS would help, but it looks like `.header` is set to `display: none;` or something similar in your CSS.

Comment: this is probably more of a comment than an answer

Comment: Yes this is what it was, thanks for the heads up in pointing that out!